# Unload Windows module and all its dynamically loaded dependencies C

Tags: c, winapi

I load a DLL with `LoadLibrary`. This DLL then dynamically loads other libraries. After unloading this library with `FreeLibrary`, the other libraries remain loaded. Is there a way to keep track of these modules and free them in C, or using the Windows API?

What about if I use C++ instead?

Comment: No.  The DLL is responsible for tracking other DLLs that it dynamically loads, and providing a function that frees them for you.  If it fails to do so, there isn't much you can do about it.  (Consider spinning off a child process to load the DLL in.)

Comment: The only way I can think of is to hook the DLL's `LoadLibrary()` and `FreeLibrary()` imports so you can intercept every time it (un)loads a DLL dynamically and discover what their `HMODULE` handles are, keeping track of them in your own list when loaded and removing them when unloaded. Then you can unload any DLLs that were not unloaded, if needed.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is in your code. Perhaps you aren't calling the finalization function exported by the DLL. Or something of that nature. Given that you think that using C++ would change things it's plausible that your code has defects.

Comment: @BlackSheep if you call LoadLibrary and then immediately FreeLibrary, do some DLLs remain loaded?

Comment: dependencies  are automatically loaded by system, when unloading your dll system call DllCanUnloadNow ( if it is present) of the other dependencies to check if it is safe to unload them.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I tried doing this, but `LoadLibrary` is never called. I don't have access to the source code for the module, so I don't know exactly how it loads the other DLLs, but I can see they're loaded into memory. I know IAT hooking is working, because I intercept `FreeLibrary` called by the same module. Any suggestions?

Comment: @BlackSheep: If the DLL in question is not calling `LoadLibrary()` to load its dependent DLLs, then it has to be linked to them statically, not dynamically, in which case the OS loader will load them automatically when you load the DLL in question, and if any of them fail to load then `LoadLibrary()` in your code would fail. So either they are loaded statically, or the DLL is calling `LoadLibrary()` and you are not hooking it correctly, or it is calling `LoadLibrary()` before you have a chance to hook it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau For anyone finding this question later, I found that `LoadLibrary` cannot directly be intercepted, but you can intercept `LoadLibraryA` and `LoadLibraryW`, as well as the ...Ex counterparts. I wonder if this catches everything, however, because  a module must be loaded to hook into, but may load some libraries dynamically on load, from within `DllMain`.

Comment: `LoadLibrary()` is not a real function, it is a preprocessor macro that resolves to either `LoadLibraryA()` or `LoadLibraryW()` depending on project configuration. But hooking `LoadLibrary...()` will only catch modules that are loaded dynamically at runtime, not linked to statically at compile-time.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes I know that this is not the way to get static libraries. I am looking for dynamic dependencies only.